# Adding a Wide Tile to WP8 app

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

How do I add a wide tile to my WP8 app(upgraded from wp 7.1)?

I tried to follow the following guide:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720574(v=vs.105).aspx

But I could not get it to work. Also WMAppManifest.xml does not have an option for a Wide Tile. The only images i can add are small, medium and large

Answer (score 2):

The article you reference is for enabling wide tiles on Windows Phone 8 devices from within a Windows Phone 7.1 project.  Your 7.1 app can still install on a WP8.  If your app has been upgraded to a Windows Phone 8 project then use the [Flip Tile Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206971%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to set the WideBackContent and WideBackground Images.

```
FlipTileData TileData = new FlipTileData()
{
   Title = "[title]",
   BackTitle = "[back of Tile title]",
   BackContent = "[back of medium Tile size content]",
   WideBackContent = "[back of wide Tile size content]",
   Count = [count],
   SmallBackgroundImage = [small Tile size URI],
   BackgroundImage = [front of medium Tile size URI],
   BackBackgroundImage = [back of medium Tile size URI],
   WideBackgroundImage = [front of wide Tile size URI],
   WideBackBackgroundImage = [back of wide Tile size URI],
};
```

Otherwise, if you really do have a 7.1 project, I recommend the [Mangopollo project](http://mangopollo.codeplex.com/) to simplify the process.  There is a [//Build/ session](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/2-019) by Thomas Fennel that may be helpful.

Comment: This throws an InvalidOperationException when I use it